# How to force a shiny app ran in Docker to use https

Tags: r, docker, https, shiny

I am trying to run a shiny application on an open port on my server. I usually run docker images using command `docker run -p 4000:3838 tag_name`, assuming that docker container has exposed port, and shiny app is running at this port.

This all works completely fine for any shiny application that is using http. But I need https.

So the Dockerfile I use consists of:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.0.1

# System libs:
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libssl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev


# R packages installed
RUN R -e "install.packages('remotes')"
RUN R -e "remotes::install_version('searchConsoleR')"
RUN R -e "remotes::install_version('googleAuthR')"
# [...] more R libraries are installed

# Copy application files to a dir
RUN mkdir /root/app
COPY . /root/app

# Expose and set run command from dir above
EXPOSE 3838
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/app', port = 3838, host = '0.0.0.0')"]
```

Then I execute `docker build -t tag_name .` and `docker run -p 4000:3838 tag_name`.

The page is available at `http://server.host:4000`

However, since I am using Google Login, I need to use https. But when I visit server's `https://server.host:4000` I see an error of page not existing.

Can someone please help?

Comment: This might be a good starting place: https://ipub.com/shiny-https/

Comment: Well it appears that there is nothing to be done in Docker - using a domain with https, and pointing this domain to the docker solves this problem. Maybe it should be done in docker, but I don't think anyone will need to force that.